# Corn snake refuses and spits out mice

Tags: snakes

I have a corn snake, 8 years, that I bought 1½ month ago. It was about to shed when I bought it, and was fed a ca 60 g mouse after shedding (about one week later).

Since then, I have tried feeding it roughly once per week, but it is consistently refusing food. I tried one other 60g mouse, and some smaller 25g mice. The first time it seemed almost scared of the mouse and looked to be actively avoiding it. (The mice are dead, of course.) In the last few attempts, it has started swallowing the mouse but then spits it out after swallowing the head. As far as I know, temperature and humidity is fine. The snake has no visible symptoms that I can see.

We have another, smaller, corn snake that we bought at the same time and that lives in another vivarium. That snake has a great appetite for the same mice that the bigger one refuses.

This is the first time I own snakes.

Any ideas of what to try or what to look for?

Comment: Please contact a vet, if you are in worry about your snakes health. And do not wait for guesses of strangers from the internet. How are the conditions in the snakes tank? Temperatures, Humidity, Light?